# NHibernate native SQL in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, nhibernate, geospatial

I have a Geography column in a table in SQL Server and would like to filter rows with a specific geometry type, e.g. all records where geometry type is 'Point'

The SQL query would look like

```
select * from GeometryTable g where g.Geography.STGeometryType() = 'Point'
```

How can I create a criteria for that? The criteria is going to be used with other criterias

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Add(<Geography.STGeometryType()>, some.Value)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Geometry>();
criteria.Add
(
  Expression.Sql(" {alias}.[Geography].STGeometryType() = ? "
  , "Point"                               // a place for your parameter
  , NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String)
);
var list = criteria.List<Geometry>();
```